# How to sort object's values to be the lowest possible

Tags: javascript, object

we have example input which is:

```
solve2([
    "Bulgaria > Sofia > 200",
    "Bulgaria > Sopot > 800",
    "France > Paris > 2000",
    "Albania > Tirana > 1000",
    "Bulgaria > Sofia > 500"
    ])
```

I basicly add them to an object like that:

```
destination= {
bulgaria: {Sofia: 500, Sopot: 800},
france: {Paris: 2000}
//and the rest the same way
}
```

So the example gives us: country > town > cost And I want to take the for example if there are 2 Sofias I want to take the one with the lower cost, but the code I will give you down just overrides them.

```
function solve2(input)
{
    let destination = {};

    input.forEach(set => {
        let [country, town, cost] = set.split(' > ');
        cost = Number(cost)

        destination[country] = {
            ...destination[country],
            [town]: cost
        };
        
    });

   console.log(destination);
}
```

this is the wanted result:

```
destination: {
  Bulgaria: { Sofia: 200, Sopot: 800 },
  France: { Paris: 2000 },
  Albania: { Tirana: 1000 }
}
```

and this is what I get:

```
destination: {
  Bulgaria: { Sofia: 500, Sopot: 800 },
  France: { Paris: 2000 },
  Albania: { Tirana: 1000 }
}
```

I get the bigger Sofia cost because its the last and it just overrides it, what I want is to get the lowest possible cost for Sofia.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your loop before you mutate `destination`:

```
    if (destination[country]?.[town] < cost) return;
```

It essentially checks whether there is already a cost for this town in your partial result, and if so, whether it is less than the cost you are currently processing. If that is true, then ignore this cost so you don't update the result with it.

Note that `?.` is a rather new operator. Check the [documentation on the optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). In short, it here evaluates `destination[country][town]`, except that it doesn't raise an exception when `destination[country]` is not defined, but instead propagates the `undefined` value to the end of the property chain.

Comment: That absolutely works, but is it possible to break it down for me because it seems really confusing?

Comment: Is the addition to my answer what you are looking for?

Comment: I am not aware of the []?.[] syntax, is it something new in js ?

Comment: Eh, yes, that's what I wrote in my answer: *"...a rather new operator"*. Check the documentation.